# iPhone SDK- Error from Debugger: The program being debugged is not being run

Tags: iphone, xcode

I followed the exact instructions on iPhone SDK Developers Portal by launching Assistant found on the first page.

But I  still get the same error even though I deleted the provisioning profile, certificates many times and repeated the same process more than once.

Please help.

Comment: Did you try a clean all targets?

Comment: yes. doesn't help... Thanks though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If you have previously used them...* check NSDebugEnabled, NSZombieEnabled, MallocStackLogging and MallocStackLoggingCompact are all disabled in the Executable info Argument's panel. You can't run with these on a device.

Answer (score 3):

It can happen if you build using an ad-hoc provisioning profile. If you followed the steps from [Building your Application with Xcode for Distribution](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/distribution/index.action), you're building with a special Entitlements.plist, in which you disallow `get-task-allow` - this prevents the debugger from connecting to the application.

Try building with another provisioning profile (e.g. a Development profile).

Comment: ad-hoc provisioning profile? i got my provisioning profile from iphone dev center launch assistant. how do i get another provisioning profile?

Comment: From the iPhone Developer Program Portal: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/provisioningprofiles/index.action

Comment: Well, then apart from restarting the device, removing all profiles, cleaning all builds etc. I don't see another feasible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Restart both the device and Xcode - this normally clears it up for me

Comment: Did you restart the device by pressing and holding the power button and home button at the same time?

Comment: Yes, i did, sigh... got started in this for 2 days now

Answer (score 0):

When you build for distribution, make sure that the "Active SDK" is set to an iPhone Device SDK and **not** an iPhone Simulator SDK.  Having it set to Simulator will still allow you to build the app, but it will give you this error when you try to run it on another device.

Also, make sure that whenever you plan on installing a new build you first change the Current Project Version in the Project Settings to a new version number.

-Drew

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you delete and reinstall all of the provisioning profiles in Organizer AND on your device (also using Organizer).  The profiles exist in 2 places.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. My solution was to quit XCode, start it again, and then do a clean build. Works for now.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the dam device!
it worked for me. I was running extensive provisioning deletion frenzy.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the debugged app from the phone, and restarting X-Code resolved this for me.