# Error from Debugger: The program being debugged is not being run

Tags: iphone, xcode

**Please dont mark this as duplicate**

I am getting this error while debugging my app on device I tried everything from these posts (see below) but no luck -

[iPhone SDK- Error from Debugger: The program being debugged is not being run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037328/iphone-sdk-error-from-debugger-the-program-being-debugged-is-not-being-run)

[XCode fails to run app on device, saying the program being debugged is not being run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727169/xcode-fails-to-run-app-on-device-saying-the-program-being-debugged-is-not-being)

Can I not run two app with the same build identifier? I use one identifier yesterday to debug one app. Now I am using the same identifier to debug another app on device.

I have tried following -

1) restart mac and iphone

2) reinstall the provision profile (both from xcode and itunes)

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK... I got it!

I have to remove the previous app from xcode organizer. Its working now!!

Answer (score 0):

You can run two app with the same build id. Are you using a distribution profile or development profile?

Comment: thanks for the advice.  It didn't work when I was using a distribution profile, but it worked fine after switching to a dev profile.